# expectation of log(1+x) if x is a gamma random variable

Tags: st.statistics, tag-removed

I would like to know if there is a closed form expression for the expectation of log(1+x) when x is a gamma random variable.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you may need Digamma function. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ has the gamma distribution with rate $\lambda$ and shape parameter $n$,  you're asking for 
$$ J(\lambda, n) = \frac{\lambda^n}{\Gamma(n)} \int_0^\infty t^{n-1} e^{-\lambda t} \log(1+t)\ dt = \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)} \int_0^\infty s^{n-1} e^{-s} \log(1+s/\lambda) \ ds$$

Using Maple, I get

$$\Psi \left( n \right) -\ln  \left( \lambda \right) +{\frac {
{\mbox{$_2$F$_2$}(1,1;\,2,2-n;\lambda)}\lambda}{n-1}}+{\frac {
 \left( -1 \right) ^{-n}\pi }{\sin \left( \pi n \right) }}-{\frac {
 \left( -1 \right) ^{-n}\pi \Gamma  \left( n,-\lambda \right) }{\sin
 \left( \pi n \right) \Gamma  \left( n \right) }}
$$

which seems to be correct when $n$ is a non-integer.  For integer values of $n$,
the result seems to be $\frac{\Gamma(n,-\lambda)}{\Gamma(n)} Ei(1,\lambda)$ plus a
polynomial in $\lambda$ of degree $n-2$.

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken, but if you are making the change of variable $s = \lambda t$, shouldn't there be an extra factor of $\lambda$ outside the integral?